Getting concave function accepted by CVX
Part of my problem is maximizing the minimum magnitude squared of vector elements (x = [x_i]). This is not a convex problem as min is taking convex expressions.
One way to work with it is by maximizing g = log_prod(d(x)), where d=[d_i] and d_i = |x_i|^2. log_prod is concave and nonincreasing, and d is convex of x. Such composition is concave, so maximizing g is a convex problem. However, CVX is not accepting such formulation.
Why is it difficult for CVX to discover such concavity? does it help to build an atom for g?

Welcome to math SE. Have a look at mathjax for your mathematical expressions.
